# python average calculator using while loop and a break to terminate assistance required

Tags: python, while-loop, average, break

okay, so the task I am attempting to complete is:
"Write a program that uses a while loop to repeatedly prompt the user for numbers and adds the numbers to a running total. When a blank line is entered, the program should print the average of all the numbers entered. You need to use a break statement to exit the while loop."

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```py
counter = 0
total = 0
while True:

    value = input("enter value:")

    if(value == " "):
        break
    else:
        counter += 1
        total += float(value)

print(total/counter)
```

[python type casting](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_casting.asp)

Comment: what's the usefulness of this in the given context? I don't think I understand...

Comment: The question has a part about str to float casting before editing.

Comment: bit i'm saying that I can't do that in this instance because when the user input is " " it attempts to convert the 'enter' into a float and returns an error message unfortunately. But I just ran it in the python IDLE and i'm not sure why it is now working when it wasn't before.... Thank you very much.